# Find subsets $W$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\mathbb{R}(W\cap V)\neq\mathbb{R}W\cap \mathbb{R}V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find subsets $W$ and $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\mathbb{R}(W\cap V)\neq\mathbb{R}W\cap \mathbb{R}V$.

I'm not sure how to find these sets. I'm sure there is an elementary solution. Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take $U$ and $V$ to be non empty disjoint subsets of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Are these sub*sets* or sub*spaces*?

Comment: Then why do you think that they can't they be disjoint?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $U$ and $V$ have a particular form. How about $U=\{(1,0,0)\}$ and $V=\{(2,0,0)\}$. Surely, these two sets are disjoint.

Comment: Answer me this: what is the set $V\cap W$ in this case? What about the set $\Bbb RV$? $\Bbb R W$?

Comment: In other words, $\Bbb RV$ and $\Bbb RW$ are each equal to the entire $x$-axis. Do you see why?

Comment: What do you mean by "choose a scalar"?

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$